# Rx sliding windows - proper cleanup?

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I've been trying to build a circuit breaker that can be configured to trip with compound rules like:

- 2 timeout exceptions within 45 seconds; or
- 50 of any other type of exception within 5 minutes

so figured the best way to do this was with sliding windows (or time-buffers whatever you want to call them).

Based on what I could find online and piece together myself I wrote this simple console app:

```
static IEnumerable<ConsoleKeyInfo> KeyPresses()
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo key;
    do
    {
        key = Console.ReadKey();
        yield return key;
    } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
}

static IObservable<int> TimeLimitedThreshold<T>(IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan timeLimit, int threshold)
{
    return source.Window(source, _ => Observable.Timer(timeLimit))
        .Select(x => x.Count())
        .Merge()
        .Where(count => count >= threshold)
        .Take(1);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting");

    var timeLimit = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    const int threshold = 3;
    var keys = KeyPresses().ToObservable(Scheduler.Default).Publish().RefCount();

    var thresholdHit = TimeLimitedThreshold(keys, timeLimit, threshold);
    thresholdHit.Subscribe(count => Console.WriteLine("THRESHOLD BREACHED! Count is: {0}", count));

    // block the main thread so we don't terminate
    keys.Where(key => key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape).FirstAsync().Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}
```

(If I should put that in a gist or pastebin instead of in the question please just say so)

Now this seems to do what I want, if I press any key 3 or more times within 5 seconds the "THRESHOLD BREACHED!!!" is printed once and nothing more happens.

My questions are:

- Is the TimeLimitedThreshold function at a sensible level of abstraction for when working with Rx.Net?
- Should I be injecting the scheduler to use when creating the Observable.Timer()?
- What cleanup am I missing if any? Memory usage when it comes to Rx.NET really baffles me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably write the threshold function the following way, taking advantage of the `Timestamp` combinator.

```
    public static IObservable<U> TimeLimitedThreshold
        <T,U>
        ( this IObservable<T> source
        , int count
        , TimeSpan timeSpan
        , Func<IList<T>,U> selector
        , IScheduler scheduler = null
        )
    {
        var tmp = scheduler == null
            ? source.Timestamp()
            : source.Timestamp(scheduler);

        return  tmp
             .Buffer(count, 1).Where(b=>b.Count==count)
             .Select(b => new { b, span = b.Last().Timestamp - b.First().Timestamp })
             .Where(o => o.span <= timeSpan)
             .Select(o => selector(o.b.Select(ts=>ts.Value).ToList()));
    }
```

As an added convenience when the trigger is fired the complete buffer that satisfies the trigger is provided to your selector function.

For example

```
 var keys = KeyPresses().ToObservable(Scheduler.Default).Publish().RefCount();
 IObservable<string> fastKeySequences = keys.TimeLimitedThreshHold
     ( 3
     , TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
     , keys => String.Join("", keys)
     );
```

The extra `IScheduler` parameter is given as the `Timestamp` method has an extra overload which takes one. This might be useful if you want to have a custom scheduler which doesn't track time according to the internal clock. For testing purposes using an [historical scheduler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/06/14/testing-rx-queries-using-virtual-time-scheduling.aspx) can be useful and then you would need the extra overload.

and here is a fully working test showing the use of a schedular. ( using XUnit and FluentAssertions for the Should().Be(..) )

```
public class TimeLimitedThresholdSpec  : ReactiveTest
{

    TestScheduler _Scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    [Fact]
    public void ShouldWork()
    {
        var o = _Scheduler.CreateColdObservable
            ( OnNext(100, "A")
            , OnNext(200, "B")
            , OnNext(250, "C")
            , OnNext(255, "D")
            , OnNext(258, "E")
            , OnNext(600, "F")
            );

        var fixture = o
            .TimeLimitedThreshold
                (3
                , TimeSpan.FromTicks(20)
                , b => String.Join("", b)
                , _Scheduler
                );

        var actual = _Scheduler
            .Start(()=>fixture, created:0, subscribed:1, disposed:1000);
        actual.Messages.Count.Should().Be(1);
        actual.Messages[0].Value.Value.Should().Be("CDE");


    }

}
```

Subscribing and is the following way

```
IDisposable subscription = fastKeySequences.Subscribe(s=>Console.WriteLine(s));
```

and when you want to cancel the subscription ( clean up memory and resources ) you dispose of the subscription. Simply.

```
subscription.Dispose()
```

Comment: Very interesting. So you're windowing based on the threshold/count and then checking the timespan between first and last. Would I be correct in thinking that any buffers that don't pass the 'o.span >= timeSpan' predicate are disposed of immediately?

Comment: Yeah. That seems the most natural to me.

Comment: One impact of your inverting of the calculation is that now you can easily see how quickly you hit the threshold, but not how many events occurred within that time window (every buffer will be the length of the threshold).

Comment: You asked for a trigger that fires when N events occur within timespan T. The event fires as soon as the condition is met. It doesn't wait till the end of the timespan.

Comment: Though I am writing a test for the above at the moment and it is not working quite right so I'll get back with an update

Comment: Oh yeah, not a criticism at all, just an observation. And firing as soon as the condition is met is probably far more useful :)

Comment: Ok. I've added a passing test to show how the code works. Writing virtual time scheduled tests is very cool. It's worth spending time understanding how it works.

Comment: I'm curious, is the Where(b=>b.Count==count) after the Buffer() call not redundant? or does that trim the possible trailing buffer if OnCompleted() is called with a partially full buffer?

Comment: Buffer doesn't quite work as you think it does. Burns me all the time. If you do ``source.Buffer(3,1)`` then when source completes you will get a buffer of length 3 then 2 then 1 as the window slides off the end. If you only ever want full buffers then you have to filter.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach that uses a single delay in favour of buffers and timers. It doesn't give you the events - it just signals when there is a violation - but it uses less memory as it doesn't hold on to too much.

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<Unit> TimeLimitedThreshold<TSource>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source,
        long threshold,
        TimeSpan timeLimit,
        IScheduler s)
    {
        var events = source.Publish().RefCount();
        var count = events.Select(_ => 1)
                        .Merge(events.Select(_ => -1)
                                    .Delay(timeLimit, s));                                               
        return count.Scan((x,y) => x + y)              
                    .Where(c => c == threshold)
                    .Select(_ => Unit.Default);           
    }
}
```

The `Publish().RefCount()` is used to avoid subscribing to the source more than one. The query projects all events to `1`, and a delayed stream of events to `-1`, then produces a running total. If the running total reaches the threshold, we emit a signal (`Unit.Default` is the Rx type to represent an event without a payload). Here's a test (just runs in LINQPad with nuget `rx-testing`):

```
void Main()
{    
    var s = new TestScheduler();
    var source = s.CreateColdObservable(
        new Recorded<Notification<int>>(100, Notification.CreateOnNext(1)),
        new Recorded<Notification<int>>(200, Notification.CreateOnNext(2)),
        new Recorded<Notification<int>>(300, Notification.CreateOnNext(3)),
        new Recorded<Notification<int>>(330, Notification.CreateOnNext(4)));

    var results = s.CreateObserver<Unit>();

    source.TimeLimitedThreshold(
        2,
        TimeSpan.FromTicks(30),
        s).Subscribe(results);

    s.Start();

    ReactiveAssert.AssertEqual(
        results.Messages,
        new List<Recorded<Notification<Unit>>> {
            new Recorded<Notification<Unit>>(
                330, Notification.CreateOnNext(Unit.Default))
        });
}
```

### Edit

After Matthew Finlay's observation that the above would also fire as the threshold is passed "on the way down", I added this version that checks only for threshold crossing in the positive direction:

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<Unit> TimeLimitedThreshold<TSource>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source,
        long threshold,
        TimeSpan timeLimit,
        IScheduler s)
    {
        var events = source.Publish().RefCount();
        var count = events.Select(_ => 1)
                        .Merge(events.Select(_ => -1)
                                    .Delay(timeLimit, s));                                                   

        return count.Scan((x,y) => x + y)          
                    .Scan(new { Current = 0, Last = 0},
                          (x,y) => new { Current = y, Last = x.Current })                        
                    .Where(c => c.Current == threshold && c.Last < threshold)
                    .Select(_ => Unit.Default);                          
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it. One thing though, if the freq goes above the threshold then falls below, this will fire twice, once when it goes above and once when it's about to go below. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for your answer. One potential extension you could do to your 2nd implementation is turn it into an IObservable<ThresholdCross> with something like:

.Where(c => c.Current == threshold && c.Last != c.Current)
.Select(c => c.Last < threshold ? ThresholdCross.Over : ThresholdCross.Under)

Comment: A quick question (plz point me to a good M to RTFM if you can), does the .Publish().RefCount() have any impacts upstream on the source or any previous observers of the source?

Comment: Well, it has an impact insofar as nothing happens in a vacuum. Publish().RefCount() is just another observer of it's source, that will make a single subscription for any number of concurrent observers. Other subscriptions to the source will not be directly affected. The only method offered by an observable is `Subscribe` - so on the face of it, there is little that an observer can do to affect upstream behaviour - but there are a lot of subtleties, such as backpressure (slow consumption), observers throwing exceptions etc. that can all have an impact...

Comment: In general though will it "break" existing code? Probably not. If there's one thing that throws people, it's the effect of making a cold observable look hot to downstream observers. There's no black and white answer, you need to be aware of what it's doing and consider the consequences in your scenario. I wrote [this blog post on the topic](http://www.zerobugbuild.com/?p=144) - a while back that might be of interest. Coincidentally the example there was very similar to your problem here.